# How can I verify doc file with POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, digital-signature, verification

I am using Apache POI to verify office word file . If my file format is docx , the verification work . But if it is doc , I got an invalid answer .

> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the OLE2 Format. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OOXML (Office Open XML) Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg HSSF instead of XSSF)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.verifyZipHeader(ZipHelper.java:179)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipFile(ZipHelper.java:237)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:134)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:117)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:257)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage$open.call(Unknown Source)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>       at com.edao.ss.docsig.ms.POIOfficeSigner.verify(POIOfficeSigner.groovy:170)
>       at com.edao.ss.docsig.ms.POIOfficeSigner$verify.call(Unknown Source)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
>       at signOfficeTest.verify(signOfficeTest.groovy:27)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Here are the official code:

```
 OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file , PackageAccess.READ)
            SignatureConfig signatureConfig = new SignatureConfig()
            signatureConfig.setOpcPackage(opcPackage)
            SignatureInfo signatureInfo = new SignatureInfo()
            signatureInfo.setSignatureConfig(signatureConfig)
            result = signatureInfo.verifySignature()
```

Comment: Did you look at https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html ?

Comment: [XML-based formats - Signing (XML Signature)](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#XML-based+formats+-+Signing+%28XML+Signature%29) means this whole part is only usable for XML-based formats of Microsoft Office. This are `*.docx` files only for `Word`. The `*.doc` files are binary format files which this signing part of `apache poi` is not made for.

Comment: @Gagravarr , yes , the code which I post is from there , it only deals with ooxml format .

Comment: @AxelRichter so does it mean that apache poi can not verify the signed *.doc file ?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know `apache poi` is neither able signing binary `*.doc` files nor validating the digital signature of binary `*.doc` files until now.